# Do the elements of this series converge to zero?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, uniform-convergence, divergent-series

Let $\{a_n\}\subset [0,\infty )$. It is well know that if $$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n < \infty$$ then we must have:
$a_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Now suppose that $a_n=a_n(u)$ with $\{a_n\}\subset [0,\infty )$ and $u \in U$ fixed in  some metric space $U$ (possibly infinite dimensional).

Asssume the following condition: there exists $C>0$ such that
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}a_n(u) < C$$
for every $u \in U$. I remark that $C$ is independent of $u$.

Can I conclude that $\sup_{u} |a_n(u)| \to 0$?

Or do I need to assume that $U$ is compact?

Comment: Take $U=[0,1]$, $a_n$ piecewise affine given by $a_n(0)=a_n(1)=0$, $a_n(2^{-n-2})=a_n(2^{-n-1})=0$, $a_n(3\times 2^{-n-3})=1$, $C=2$.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean. Is the supremum taken for fixed $n$, over all $u$, and then $n \to \infty$? In this case, the answer is no? For each $n$, just impose that at least one $u$ has $a_n(u)$ huge---this doesn't affect the summability of that particular sequence, it's free to decay quickly (or be zero) after that point.

Answer (score 2):

The topology of $U$ makes no difference since $U$ is really just acting as an index set here.
Take for example $U = \mathbb N$ and consider the sequences
$$ a_n(u) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{if $u = n$}, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases} $$
(It's just the infinite grid with diagonal $1$.)

Then
$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb N} a_n(u) = 1 $$
for all $u$ (i.e., summing across the grid) and
$$ \sup_{u} a_n(u) = 1 $$
for all $n$ (i.e., taking max/sup down the grid).

Change $U$ to be any other (infinite) set and you can play exactly the same game, it just won't look as neat if you can't easily compare the $u$ indices and the $n$ indices.